# Is it important when using React propTypes validations to check them at every level?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm working on a part of a React app in which a high-level component creates and passes certain `props` down through a few layers of components that don't use them to a final component that does.

When validating `props` with `propTypes`, is there a good reason to list these `props` to be checked at every level, going down through the layers? Or is it acceptable to check them only in the final component that uses them?

It seems to me that the former method is redundant; the latter seems to make more sense to me, but I'm curious if there is a reason why I ought to do the former. I haven't seen any discussion on it, which could mean it's an unimportant question, but I'd be interested to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you about if you use props only for dril down for children in the tree, it can be done only once at the leaf components, where you realy use this data. I recently find out that one more place is important for props validation: the components which fetch data from out of app scope, such as backend, because sometimes the structure of the data changes or the data types, then it will be dificult to find which part is broken without props validation.